# angularjs ngOptions having 2 object property as label and tracking by Id

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

Okay so i have an object that contains a few object named as professionals
the structure looks like that

`lstProf=[{firstName:'tony',lastName:'bob',id:188},{...},{...}];`

I want my select field to show firstName + lastName and track by ID

somehow this is not working :

```
    <select class="input-antoine section2-control"  
    data-ng-options="prof.id as prof.firstName +' 
     '+prof.lastName for prof in lstProfs track by prof.id"
    data-ng-model="patient.treatingProfessionnal" 
    data-convert-to-number>
    </select>
```

my ng-model is also an int.

what am i doing wrong.

Comment: [Be careful when using select as and track by in the same expression.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#-select-as-and-track-by-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lstProf=[{firstName:'tony',lastName:'bob',id:188},{...},{...}];

<select data-ng-options="prof.id as prof.firstName +' 
     '+prof.lastName for prof in lstProf track by prof.id"
    data-ng-model="personById" 
    data-convert-to-number>
</select>
```

First you have typo in the question.
Collection is named lstProf, then you are referencing to it in the ng-options in plural form lstProfs. 
Second according to documentation as  Pankaj Parkar brought up there is the caution of using select as with track by.
Whatever property is in the `track by`, quoting documentation
`track by expression is also applied to the ngModel`.

Prepared simple plunker to expose difference of approach to your problem.
https://plnkr.co/edit/Rx8JfTee0JnyQa7UD1qE?p=preview

Comment: Thank you so much !